# Why do the 'where' line produces a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following consult in MySQL:

```
select a.transcription_id, a.speaker, a.sentence_text, a.tokenize_sentences
from sentences_type as a
where (length(a.sentence_text) - length(replace(a.sentence_text, ' ', '')) + 1) > 5
inner join(
select b.transcription_id, count(b.transcription_id) as conta
from sentences_type as b
group by transcription_id
having conta = 2) as c
on a.transcription_id = c.transcription_id;
```

When I take off the 'where' line [where (length(a.sentence_text) - length(replace(a.sentence_text, ' ', '')) + 1) > 5], it runs perfectly. When I try to run the code with it, it produces a syntax error:

> Error SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join(select b.transcription_id, count(b.transcription_id) as conta from' at line 4

Comment: syntax error because WHERE clause is misplaced

Answer (score 1):

In your query the `WHERE` clause should be after the `JOIN`. The following query will work:

```
SELECT a.transcription_id,
       a.speaker,
       a.sentence_text,
       a.tokenize_sentences
FROM sentences_type AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT b.transcription_id,
           COUNT(b.transcription_id) AS conta
    FROM sentences_type AS b
    GROUP BY transcription_id
    HAVING conta = 2
    ) AS c
    ON a.transcription_id = c.transcription_id
WHERE (LENGTH(a.sentence_text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(a.sentence_text, ' ', '')) + 1) > 5;
```

Comment: If the answer helped to solve your problem, you may [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is at the wrong place

```
select a.transcription_id, a.speaker, a.sentence_text, a.tokenize_sentences
from sentences_type as a
inner join(
    select b.transcription_id, count(b.transcription_id) as conta
    from sentences_type as b
    group by transcription_id
    having conta = 2) as c on a.transcription_id = c.transcription_id
where (length(a.sentence_text) - length(replace(a.sentence_text, ' ', '')) + 1) > 5;
```